# CYPHER get edges between nodes

Tags: cypher

I currently have a graph with containing routes that have Id's and need to find all routes between A and E. I don't need to do a shortest path as all the routes have Id's.

I currently run multiple queries and was hoping to do it in one.

1. Get all edges connected to A (1,2,3)

   MATCH (n:Node  {Id: "A"})-[s:Edge]->(:Node) RETURN s.Id
2. Get all edges connected to E (1,3)

   MATCH (:Node)-[s:Edge]->(n:Node {Id: "E"}) RETURN s.Id
3. Keep Id's where they match (1,2)
4. Retrieve all edges where id's match.

   FOR EACH RESULT WHERE ID's MATCH
   MATCH (s:Node)-[e:Edge {Id: id})->(e:Node) RETURN ALL

(1)A -> B -> C -> D -> E

(2)A -> B -> C -> D -> E

Can this be done in one query? I have the feeling an UNWIND is involved and I also couldn't find how to do a LEFT INNER JOIN to do that.

Examples:
If I want all routes between A and E, it should return 2. If I want all edges between A and D, it should return 3.

[image: Sample]

```
Node {

string Id;
}


Edge {
long Id;
}
```

Comment: So, basically you want all paths from A to E, where all relationships in the path have the same ID?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think there's a need to use a shortest path algorithm.

Comment: I think I do need to find a path unless add 'Order' property on the edge.

Answer (score 0):

The hard part here is "where all rel ids are the same", but here is how you can do that check by grabbing the first relation in the path, and comparing it to the rest.

```
MATCH p=(start{id:'A'})-[*..10]->(end{id:'E'})
WHERE ALL(r in RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE r.id=HEAD(RELATIONSHIPS(p)).id)
RETURN p
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need all the edges and not just the first. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Liam, the first rel is only used for the base id to use to verify they all have the same id. P is the path, so using `RETURN RELATIONSHIPS(p)` would return all the relationships in the path.